# Deposit from paypal to coinbase

Tags: paypal, coinbase-api, coinbase-php

I want to transfer/deposit money from attached paypal account to coinbase.
But all api methods dont work.

1. Get payment ID - client.get_payment_methods()

"label": "Daily PayPal limit"

2. Make buy/deposit methods.
   Deposit return - **Can't deposit with this account**, but in first step

> "allow_buy": true,
> "allow_deposit": true,
> "allow_sell": false,
> "allow_withdraw": true,

Buy method - return operation ID, but

```
txs = client.get_buys(BUY_ID)

      "status": "canceled",
```

How can i do it?!